# Passing a custom class by value

Tags: c#, collections

Let's say I have a custom class CustomClass, and I have a collection deriving from CollectionBase class named CustomClassCollection. Let's say I do something like this:

```
CustomClassCollection a = new CustomClassCollection();
CustomClassCollection b = a;
```

When I change the CustomClass elements in `a`, the elements in `b` are also changed. How should I write these classes so that when I assign `a` to `b` and change the elements of `b`, `a` still stays the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a `Clone` (implementing `IClonable`) or a copy constructor for `CustomClassCollection`.

Comment: When I implement it and assign an instance to another, is it going to be cloned automatically or should I call the `Clone` method manually?

Comment: this will *not* resolve an issue of OP. The references still points to the **same** memory, even in 2 different collections.

Comment: @Tigran - how so? with `IClonable`, you are supposed to create a new reference.

Comment: What if I override the `=` operator and make it a cloning operation?

Comment: @hattenn - you can't overload it.

Comment: @DanielA.White: it's not *really* clear from your post, where that Cloone has to be implemented.

Comment: Is there a way to make it work so that when I assign one to another, it gets cloned?

Comment: @hattenn no. this would make your code very difficult to troubleshoot. i would consider a different design.

Comment: So creating a collection that is passed by value is bad design?

Comment: @hattenn no its just that you have 2 collections that are really linked in such a special way.

Comment: I don't have two collections. I just have one class that represents a data and a collection of it.

Comment: I don't understand. I just implemented `Clone` method in the collection and just implemented as "foreach element add it to the new instance and return that", and now it works. I expected it not to work. Aren't those elements in the original list get added by reference when you add them to a new instance in the clone method?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with `MemberwiseClone();`

```
YourType other = (YourType) YourInstance.MemberwiseClone();
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `Clone` method on the type **inside** collection.

After you can implement method on collection itself, that clonning each element of *source* collection adds it to *destination* .

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

[Serializable]
class CustomClass
{
    int _id;
    string _value;

    public CustomClass(int id, string value)
    {
        _id = id;
        _value = value;
    }
}

[Serializable]
class CustomClassCollection
{
    private IList<CustomClass> _list = null;

    public CustomClassCollection()
    {
        _list = new List<CustomClass>();
    }

    public void Add(CustomClass a)
    {
        _list.Add(a);
    }
}

public static class CloneManager
{
    public static T Clone<T>(this T source)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable.", "source");
        }

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (stream)
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
        CustomClassCollection a = new CustomClassCollection();
        CustomClassCollection b = ObjectCopier.Clone<CustomClassCollection>(a);

        a.Add(new CustomClass(1, "A"));
        a.Add(new CustomClass(2, "B"));
        a.Add(new CustomClass(3, "C"));

        b.Add(new CustomClass(1, "A"));
        b.Add(new CustomClass(2, "B"));
```